# How can I open apk file I just download from react-native Webview?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-webview

I am trying to use react-native-webview to download Android apk file. It could download apk file actually!

But How can I know when file is download success and get file path or automatically install the apk file I just download?

is there any good ideal to make it happen? very thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once downloaded to your device path, you can try this with two modules.

You must have two modules installed and available. `react-native-file-viewer` and `react-native-document-picker`

**Example**

```js
import FileViewer from 'react-native-file-viewer';
import { DocumentPicker, DocumentPickerUtil } from 'react-native-document-picker';

DocumentPicker.show({
  filetype: [DocumentPickerUtil.allFiles()],
}, (error, res) => {
  if(res) {
    FileViewer.open(res.uri)
    .then(() => {
      // success
    })
    .catch(_err => {
      // error
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: it seems that webpage in webview is not what I can control. Even I dont know weather user clicked download Button.

Comment: @xiaoshitou You said you could download APK. Isn't that right?

Comment: Yes.I cant download apk file with react-native-webview ,but can not know where file download is and how to let it be installed automatically

Comment: Didn't you say in the question that you can download?